# Set (keyboard)focus to parent container when child with (keyboard)focus is removed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two buttons in a canvas (with Focusable=true)
I use the tab key to select one button and press enter to remove the button
I want (keyboard)focus to go back to canvas, but it goes to window

Demo:
MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Canvas">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Canvas Name="Canvas" Focusable="True">
            <Button Click="RemoveSelf">Button 1</Button>
            <Button Canvas.Left="100" Click="RemoveSelf">Button 2</Button>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void RemoveSelf(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Canvas.Children.Remove((UIElement)sender);
        }
    }
}
```

When the application starts, everything is red.
As soon as you press TAB, canvas becomes green
Press TAB again, and Button 1 becomes green, canvas becomes red
Press ENTER, button 1 disappears but canvas does not become green
I want canvas to become green

Answer (score 1):

You can move focus to Canvas manually:

```
Canvas.Focus();
```

In your button callback:

```
private void RemoveSelf(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas.Children.Remove((UIElement)sender);
    Canvas.Focus();
}
```

**UPDATE:**
You can move focus to the next element using `UIElement.MoveFocus` method in code-behind:

```
private void RemoveSelf(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is UIElement element)
    {
        element.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        // ...
    }
}
```

Also this way you can move focus from window to canvas.

Comment: I would like to find a more automatic way to do it, imagine having many different elements inside the canvas, which don't remove themselves using codebehind.

Comment: Thank you for your update, I don't actually have a "RemoveSelf" function in my actual use case, so it can't be used to change focus. Also it seems that would move the focus to the next element in the Canvas, but I need my focus to be on the Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following in my XAML:

```
<Canvas Name="Canvas" Focusable="True" IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged="FocusWithinChanged">
```

And added the method in my codebehind:

```
private void FocusWithinChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var flag = e.NewValue as bool?;
    if (flag != true)
    {
        Canvas.Focus();
    }
}
```

This appears to move the (keyboard)focus to the Canvas as soon as I press ENTER on a button, which is what I need.